# Changing the default color of the pencil in Microsoft Paint

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-paint

By default the pencil color is black in Microsoft Paint. Is there any way to changing the default color to another color?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/550092/is-it-possible-to-save-settings-for-microsoft-paint

Comment: Yeah, I just want the color to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is no way to do this.

Comment: more accurately, there is no way to do this without modifying the paint executable binary.