# How to change default rectangle border thickness in MS Paint

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-paint

When I open MS Paint (Win 8), the default border thickness is set to the thickness depicted in the picture.

[image]

Is there a way to change the default rectangle border thickness?

Comment: Unfortunately MS Paint is a very basic app and it does not supports saving your preferences. It only saves the last canvas size. A similar question was asked by another user, take a look at it [here](http://superuser.com/questions/550092/is-it-possible-to-save-settings-for-microsoft-paint).

Comment: @Ayan - thanks for your comment. I wasn't aware of the other question. Marking mine as duplicate.